# Creating a floating, editable and scrollable list in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollable

I want to show a list of items when the user clicks an overlay item on a map. The user should be able to select any of these items and edit them. The list can have many items (more than that can fit in one active screen) therefore it needs to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an activity with a transparent background, then launch that activity on top.  From there you can make the list editable, by using a custom list adapter & updating the data contained within the adapter.

Comment: Do you have any example/open source project that does something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: in your application manifest, just add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to the activity where you're rendering the list.